# Translating WordPress

Tags: wordpress, localization, translation

I've got a multilingual WordPress installation with buddypress using wpml.
The problem is for example my Spanish users fill in location in Spanish so then for example my English users can't find Spanish users by location because it's in Spanish and viceversa.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is too broad to give a precise coding solution, but here are two ideas:

(1) Geotag the users instead of using free text searches.

Convert a user's location to geocoordinates when they enter it into their profile. Then do the same when someone does a text search, giving results in order of proximity.

You'll need an API for this. Have a look at [Google's Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).

(2) Much easier, but much more limiting:

Limit locations to a dropdown list of nearest major location. Store these as generic identifiers for searching, but display them on screen in the user's required language.

Comment: I've achieved the second one but only with a list of all countries.
Anyway to get cities aswell??